# В хроме и сафари не выполняется функция .animate()

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, javascript, safari

Добрый день, прошу помощи.

Есть простенький скрипт слайдера JS + Jquery. При клике по стрелке картинка сменяется. Все казалось бы просто. Возможно я что то не усмотрел, но у мене в браузерах Хром и Сафари картинки не листаются.
Сама функция, которая выполняет отображение (`visibl()`), вызывается (`alert` всплывает), а вот предыдущая строка:

```
$(Id_Img).animate(){
left: Position + 'px'
}, 1000 );
```

не отрабатывается. Первоначально складывается мнение, что `.animate()` в Хроме не отрабатывает, но судя с документации быть такого не может.
В чем косяк, и как его исправить?

Исходники:

- http://hotpart.com.ua/tree/somara/js/script.js
- http://hotpart.com.ua/tree/somara/Index.html

Comment: Шок :( Иногда даже слов не хватает. Я вообще удивляюсь, что у вас что-то хоть как-то работает. Такое количество грубейших ошибок начиная с разметки, заканчивая CSS и JS, что просто руки опускаются. В данной ситуации, помочь вам - это значит полностью переписать всё, абсолютно всё от начала до конца. Чего стоит только одно то, что у вас идентификаторы прописаны для нескольких элементов... В общем, вердикт - порвать, выбросить, забыть и начать с чистого листа, предварительно выучив азы HTML, CSS и JS.

Answer (score 2):

Может дело просто в скобке?

```
$(Id_Img).animate({
left: Position + 'px'
}, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 1):

В `index.html`

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        CreateTegImages();
   });
```

А в `script.js` эти строки уберите.

Comment: Если на то пошло, то

    $(CreateTegImages);

Answer (score 0):

надо в кавычках писать то есть $('Id_Img'), так же если в cms какой ни будь используется, то лучше написать jQuery('Id_Img')